# Nested If/Then with Nested Loops; Doesn't stop when desired

Tags: vba, loops, excel, nested-loops

The goal is to have the loop go through the "Source" workbook. Where it satisfies the following condition

```
If Source_Sheet.Range("B" & Z) = "LCA" And Source_Sheet.Range("D" & Z) = "Resgate Final Passivo Cliente" And Source_Sheet.Range("H" & Z) = "9007230"
```

It will then trigger the next if/then statement (within those that satisfy the first if/then), which will compare the A column in the Workbook(source).Sheet1 with Q column in Workbook(affected).Dados. Where they are the same it will then subtract the value of the corresponding F column cell(in Source) from the  T column in Workbook(affected).Dados.

I've pasted the entire code below. What is currently happening is that it subtracts the values properly from the T Column. But it doesn't stop after subtracting just one time. It subtracts EIGHT times and then stops.

```
 Dim Source As Workbook
Dim Affected As Workbook

Dim Dados As Worksheet
Dim Source_Sheet As Worksheet

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim v As Variant
Dim N As Long
Dim M As Long
Dim FinalRow As Long

Set Source = Workbooks("ResgatesEmissões.xlsb")
Set Affected = Workbooks.Open("\\dsapc429pfs.pactual.net\homefolder02$\wellsty\Desktop\LCA_LCI Macro Writing\New - Macro Writing - Controle de Lastro LCA.xlsm")

Set Dados = Affected.Sheets("Dados")
Set Source_Sheet = Source.Sheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = Source_Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
N = Dados.Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
M = Source_Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For Z = 1 To LastRow
If Source_Sheet.Range("B" & Z) = "LCA" And Source_Sheet.Range("D" & Z) = "Resgate Final Passivo Cliente" And Source_Sheet.Range("H" & Z) = "9007230" Then
    For i = 1 To M
        v1 = Source_Sheet.Cells(i, "A").Value
        v2 = Source_Sheet.Cells(i, "F").Value
        For j = 1 To N
            If v1 = Dados.Cells(j, "Q").Value Then
            Dados.Cells(j, "T").Value = Dados.Cells(j, "T").Value - v2
            Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
Else: End If
Next Z
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the subtraction line. Each time it stops here check the values of z,i,j and the values in the relevant cells.

Comment: Which is equal to EIGHT: LastRow  or M or N?

Comment: The only thing that I've found that equals eight is the number of cells that satisfy the condition of: If Source_Sheet.Range("B" & Z) = "LCA" And Source_Sheet.Range("D" & Z) = "Resgate Final Passivo Cliente" And Source_Sheet.Range("H" & Z) = "9007230"

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. It just continued to keep looping through. The new loop looks like this and works perfectly.

```
 For Z = 1 To LastRow
If Source_Sheet.Range("B" & Z) = "LCA" And Source_Sheet.Range("D" & Z) = "Resgate Final Passivo Cliente" And Source_Sheet.Range("H" & Z) = "9007230" Then
        v1 = Source_Sheet.Cells(Z, "A").Value
        v2 = Source_Sheet.Cells(Z, "F").Value
        For j = 1 To N
            If v1 = Dados.Cells(j, "Q").Value Then
            Dados.Cells(j, "T").Value = Dados.Cells(j, "T").Value - v2
            Exit For
            End If
        Next j
Else: End If
Next Z
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to have this action for only one cells that satisfy the condition (per you comment above, then you need to exit ALL For...Next loops, not just the internal one:

```
    Dim bStop As Boolean
    For Z = 1 To LastRow
        bStop = False
        If Source_Sheet.Range("B" & Z) = "LCA" And Source_Sheet.Range("D" & Z) = "Resgate Final Passivo Cliente" And Source_Sheet.Range("H" & Z) = "9007230" Then
            For i = 1 To M
                v1 = Source_Sheet.Cells(i, "A").Value
                v2 = Source_Sheet.Cells(i, "F").Value
                For j = 1 To N
                    If v1 = Dados.Cells(j, "Q").Value Then
                        Dados.Cells(j, "T").Value = Dados.Cells(j, "T").Value - v2
                        bStop = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
                If bStop Then Exit For
            Next i
            If bStop Then Exit For
        End If
    Next Z
```